# В Телеграме же, не в Телеграмме?

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

Надеюсь, все хотя бы слышали об этом приложении. Писал и при склонении с одной М, но когда только что стал что-то гуглить, увидел гораздо больше вариантов с двумя М, как если бы это было от слова *телеграмма.*

Comment: Вопрос грамотности в использовании гугла. Запрос должен быть, во-первых, заковычен, и, во-вторых, указан период времени с 2005 годов примерно. Еще не помешает учесть прописные буквы. Тогда, как и должно быть, превалирует статистика "в телеграме" над "в телеграмме": 1 к 4 примерно

Comment: С 2005 года вы хотели сказать?

Comment: По запросу *галочки в Телеграме* и такому же с двумя М результатов больше с двумя М.

Comment: "С 2005 годов" как фигуральное выражение вполне корректно. Ср "Пушкиных у нас нет."

Comment: А-а, с две тысячи пят**ых**? Но я привёл аргумент.

Comment: Да, "с 2005-х" надо было написать. "Галочки в Телеграмме/Телеграме" = 841/10. Но если так "в Телеграмме/Телеграме"", то уже 1 млн / 4 млн. То есть тут какие-то локальные факторы сыграли роль, а в целом гугл подтверждает, что правильно "в телеграме"

Comment: На галочках-то не подтверждает!

Comment: Тогда о галочках надо было написать в вопросе с самого начала. Там речь о галочках не велась.

Comment: Странно, в моём гугле "Галочки в Телеграмме/Телеграме" = 14/10 (или 22/12 если учитывать "похожие" ссылки). Не могли бы Вы уточнить, где можно увидеть "гораздо больше"?

Comment: Я уже не первый раз замечаю, что гугл у всех по-разному показывает статистику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, Тёмыч, да.

> [Telegram](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram) — кроссплатформенный мессенджер с функциями VoIP,
> позволяющий обмениваться текстовыми, голосовыми и видеосообщениями,
> стикерами и фотографиями, файлами многих форматов. Также можно
> совершать видео- и аудиозвонки, организовывать конференции,
> многопользовательские группы и каналы.

Проект финансируется Павлом Дуровым бла-бла-бла. Означенный Павел захотел дать своему детищу английское имечко — в своём праве. Какие две "m", м?

Мы используем кальку с английского, а не переводы переводим, вот.

> Его телеграмма наделала шуму в Генштабе. — His telegram created a stir
> in the General Staff.

Comment: Спасибо, Галин!)

Comment: Очень распространена просто эта ошибка! Народ не задумывается о том, как правильно.